# Java Spark data structure to read records from .csv and perform data analysis

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have CSV file, that has millions lines of records (Around 2GB) and 15 columns. I need to calculate different metrics in this file, such as median, mean, average and some other statistic.

I’m new to Spark, and not sure what Spark Data Structure I need to hold all this records. Should I create class that will represent one line of the data, called  `MyClass`, and then read the data into `JavaRDD<MyClass>`?

Or it’s better to use DataFrame? How to create DataFrame from `.csv` file and how to create `JavaRDD<MyClass>` from `.csv` file?

**UPDATE**: if it's matter, `.csv` file doesn't have schema. Schema lives into separate `.csv` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe is the newer, recommended API. You should avoid using RDDs unless you really need the lower level functionality. It's trivial to compute the summary statistics from dataframe. Look into the `describe()` method for dataframe and `percentile_approx` in spark-sql.